# Bash Linux random CLI Password generator and `<`

Tags: bash, shell

I recently discovered this method for generating a 9 character password from the linux prompt in bash:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9_ | head -c9
```

What is `<` doing?

Comment: I suggest changing subject of your posting, since the answer doesn't seem to be in direct relation with Subject line. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you're wondering, this is just a [less common usage](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) of the input redirector. The shell takes the file specified as input and its default behavior is to echo it to stdout.

The breakdown of the command you have:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9_ | head -c9
```

`<`: Input redirector. Shell echoes contents of file (/dev/urandom)

`tr`: from `tr --help`:

> Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input,
>   writing to standard output.

The options -dc are equivalent to --delete --complement, which means to delete the complement of the following set of characters, i.e. all characters NOT in the set. That excludes non alphanumeric & underscore characters in your example.

`head`: print the first few lines of something (default 10). the -c9 switch tells it how many bytes to print instead of lines.

Put it all together and you get, "print me the first 9 alphanumeric or underscore bytes from /dev/urandom". :)

Comment: It is "standard", in the sense that any POSIX sh should parse redirections out of anywhere in a simple command (even in the middle). It's just uncommon to not put them at the end.

Comment: You know, I almost went back and changed that wording, so I went ahead and updated it now. You're right... I was basically just quoting the page in the link. It's more proper to say it's "less common" because as far as I know it's a very well-supported usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try `< /usr/include/stdio.h head` — it should be file, dude.

In case you need a program output being given as file, it can be done this way: `vim <(echo test)`

Comment: Apologies for the unaccept, palintropos' answer is just too thorough

Comment: @MikePennington, I don't think that's the more is better, but nevermind anyways.